# While submitting the form chrom displaying "Unable to decode value" in post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to submit the form value

```
       <!doctype html><html id="nameId" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>Demo</title><style type="text/css"> p{margin:10px 0; padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{display:block; margin:0; padding:0;}img,a img{border:0; height:auto; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;}.mcnPreviewText{display:none !important;}#outlook a{padding:0;}....
```

the value is storing in the database but the issue is it displaying (unable to decode value) in form post

Comment: I don't find any php code also your html doesn't help as it is incomplete.

Comment: That is my form input value that is not html code .I need to store this value in database by ajax,PHP

Comment: Please upload all your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or

Using encodeURIComponent to wrap the value fixed the problem.

Broken:

`?value=${myValue}`

Working:

`?value=${encodeURIComponent(myValue)}`

Comment: In my form value there nothing like(Ω ,µ )